# Cant find expected output of textbox from form of PHP

Tags: php, forms

I have a textbox element in reg.php file . The code for this element is defined as below :

```
  <input type="text" name="name" size="25" maxlength="25">
```

Here is the code for form defined in reg.php :

```
  <Form name="registration" method="post" action="confirm.php" enctype="multitype/form-data">
```

In the confirm.php I want to show the value of string that is typed in the textbox . For this reason I have typed the following code :

```
                <?php
                    if(empty($name))
                        die("No Name Submitted");
                    else if(strlen($name)<5)
                        die("invalid name");
                    else
                        echo $name;
                ?>
```

But when I type a string and then press enter , The string "No Name is Submitted" is echoed in the browser . Why ? I have tried several times . But the result of the code is same as previous .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `$_POST['name']` , because you are post data and you can get by `$_POST`

Comment: Also, name is a reserved word in lots of places, give your textbox a more descriptive name!

Comment: The question is marked as "eligible for bounty in 2 days " ? What is the meaning of this statement ?

Comment: Plz answer of my question  mentioned in comment  .

Comment: @OcenaPothik , it means you can set bounty of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get your string from HTML? you should use `$_GET` or `$_POST` for getting your string from HTML and then try to check the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['name']) && trim($_POST['name']) != ""){

                       if(strlen($_POST['name'])>5)echo $_POST['name'];
                       else die("invalid name");
                    }else{
                     die("No Name Submitted");
                    }

                ?>
```

check form with check post data
you can use trim or other clear string function